# Nvim can not detect focus change inside tmux sessions

Tags: neovim, line-numbers, tmux

I use the following setting for automatic line number toggle.

```
augroup numbertoggle
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter,FocusGained,InsertLeave * set relativenumber
  autocmd BufLeave,FocusLost,InsertEnter   * set norelativenumber
augroup END
```

But it seems that this setting does not work inside tmux.  If I open two tmux panes side by side and open  a file with Neovim in one pane and then switch to another tmux pane, the relative line number in Neovim does not change to absolute number. How to fix this issue?

Besides, I use `set -g mouse on` inside `~/.tmux.conf` so that I can use mouse clicks to change tmux panes, if that information is relevant.

Comment: Im not sure about the Focus events, but you havent left the buffer or entered insert mode when you switch, so it makes sense those dont trigger.

Comment: Could you rename this question to something like "FocusGaine/Lost not detected in tmux"? And perhaps combine your own answer and the answer of @BLayer (and than accept it)? That way we would get a proper answered question, that covers NeoVim and Vim.

Comment: The plugin was written for both neovim and vim users. I guess it's possible that there's since been a general fix applied to neovim but the neovim dev's words don't indicate one way or the other. They, like OP, could just happen to have a terminal type that needs only the tmux config.

Comment: @Ralf, only experienced may know what `FocusGained/Lost` event mean. Before I ask this question, I have never heard of these events. I don't think the new title is useful for new users. For experienced user, they may have solved this issue themselves and do not need answer here.

Comment: My $0.02 on the subject change: Maybe there aren't many people who know the event names but there are plenty enough people who understand the notion of focus, generally speaking. You could use something like "Focus change inside tmux doesn't trigger applicable autocmd events".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/9486) on Neovim repo and get the right answer.

We need to turn on the `focus-events` for tmux. Edit the tmux config file `~/.tmux.conf` and add the following setting:

```
set -g focus-events on
```

Refresh the tmux session and the automatic relative line number toggle should work as expected now.

**Edit:**
For some users using some terminal, setting `focus-events` for tmux solely does not work. You may also need to install the vim plugin [described in B Layer's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18537/11054)

Comment: Great, that this is solved for you. I tried it with Vim 8.1.712 and tmux 2.1 in GNOME-terminal and I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Maybe your tmux version is too low. My tmux version is 2.8-rc.

Comment: @Ralf See if the plugin mentioned in my answer works for you. (It has helped me.)

Comment: In fact, I just noticed that the plugin's README mentions GNOME specifically as one of the tested terminal types so that's a hopeful sign.

Comment: @BLayer Yes, I can confirm that with the plugin vim-tmux-focus-events, at least "FocusGained" is detected. It didn't work for "FocusLost". (GNOME-terminal, Vim 8.2.722).

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of this issue is that xterm-compatible terminals (at least...there may be others) emit a certain control sequence when focus is gained/lost from a terminal window. Rather than Vim, say, intercepting said sequences and triggering `FocusGained`/`FocusLost` events in response it ignores them. Fortunately someone wrote a vim/neovim plugin that will do exactly that called [vim-tmux-focus-events](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events).

It seems not all terminals need the plugin to solve the problem. As OP notes in their answer it was enough in their case to simply enable the tmux `focus-events` setting in their `tmux.conf` file:

```
 set -g focus-events on
```

And actually this is required regardless; the plugin's README instructs one to enable same.

So try the tmux setting alone first. If *no-joy* try the plugin, too. (I'm trying to confirm it but I believe one must be using tmux 1.8 or later for all this.)

(As a bonus the plugin also helps with getting [`autoread`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'autoread') to work in terminals/tmux, too.)

**Update:** Just noticed that someone submitted back in '13 [a patch for Vim](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/ASn8QqQqVe0) that would obviate the need for the plugin. Doesn't look to be getting much love.

Answer (score 2):

As  D. Ben Knoble said in his comment, "you haven't left the buffer or entered insert mode when you switch, so it makes sense those don't trigger.

And the help for FocusGained / Lost says: "Only for the GUI version and a few console versions where this can be detected." I guess the console never lost/gained focus as you switch tmux panes. So even if the console you use could detect focus lost/gained, it would not trigger.

Looking at the source of Vim, the comment on the function `ui_focus_change` in `ui.c` says:

```
/*
 * Called when focus changed.  Used for the GUI or for systems where this can
 * be done in the console (Win32).
 */
```

Comment: I thought that clicking another tmux pane has moved the cursor out of the vim window.

Comment: @jdhao FocusGained/Lost in the console seems Windows only. See update.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I will add an issue to Neovim repo to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: This depends on the terminal. I believe some terminals are actually being able to process Focus events and do.

Comment: The developer of nvim solved this issue. See [my answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18529/15292).

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is really old, but for me, substituting WinEnter and WinLeave for FocusGained and FocusLost fixed the problem in my VIM terminal.